# Import formats of ExpressJS with Typescript

Tags: express, typescript

I am having difficulty with the import format for importing Express.js into TypeScript (I am using the @types, already installed)

I was importing like this

```
import { Application} from "express";
```

so in my code I can now do this

```
private expressApp: Application;
```

The problem is that I wish to create a new express app, so I assume I have to do the following,

```
      this.expressApp = new Application();
```

But it reports an error, saying it's only a type.

I also tried doing

```
import * as express from "express";
```

but now everything is hung off of Express so I have express.Application which is a little ugly. And it still not possible to do a `new express()`.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sort of stuff tripped me up a lot when I was getting to grips with TypeScript, the problem is you're using "Application" which is actually just a type definition and not the object itself. You want something like this:

```
import * as express from 'express';
const app: express.Application = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Here I'm using express.Application to denote the type. express.Application is simply an interface which denotes the type. Otherwise you'll notice my code is identical to the [Express "Hello World" example](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html):

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes that worked, any way to combin import * as express from 'express' and import { Application} from "express"; onto one line ?

Comment: @Martin sadly not, you could add a second import if it was the "express." that you wanted to remove from the typing though. But as the express function is the default export, you need that to create a new app. If this has answered your question, would you mind hitting the tick?